# Resize WPF Canvas control not maintaining aspect ratio correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using the resize code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660672/how-can-i-resize-a-rotated-control-without-change-the-aspect-ratio-based-on-the) which works perfectly when testing but when placed into a real application (with a larger render time) the aspect ratio no is no longer maintained.  If you move the mouse slowly or wiggle in certain directions you can make the control distort out of its original aspect ratio and it only seems to happen once in an actual application.

I'm not 100% sure but I wonder if its because it uses `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` to calculate the current ratio and that those values might not always be up to date.

Some of the related code, the rest is available on the question linked above:

Called on drag

```
this.CheckAspectRatio(ref dragDeltaHorizontal, ref dragDeltaVertical, item.ActualHeight / item.ActualWidth);
```

The function itself

```
private void CheckAspectRatio(ref double? dragDeltaHorizontal, ref double? dragDeltaVertical, double aspectRatio)
{
    double? dragValue = null;
    if (dragDeltaVertical.HasValue && dragDeltaHorizontal.HasValue)
    {
        dragValue = Math.Max(dragDeltaVertical.Value, dragDeltaHorizontal.Value);
    }
    else if (dragDeltaVertical.HasValue)
    {
        dragValue = dragDeltaVertical;
    }
    else if (dragDeltaHorizontal.HasValue)
    {
        dragValue = dragDeltaHorizontal;
    }

    if (dragValue.HasValue)
    {
        dragDeltaVertical = dragValue.Value * aspectRatio;
        dragDeltaHorizontal = dragValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution seems to be complicated for a simple problem. could you post some sample images showing the resize handles/sides etc. appreciated if you could also share the xaml or c# code used for generating the elements.

Comment: Hey, why does it seem complicated? Resizing an arbitary control is not native to WPF and quite a difficult task, unless you know different? :)

Comment: My comment was intended to the answering code in the linked post. By simple I mean to say that, you may consider using [UIElement.ManipulationDelta Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of DragEvents. also do not forget to set the ManipulationMode otherwise you may not receive the scale values as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004620/manipulationdelta-only-translation-has-values-scale-and-rotation-is-always-i

Comment: The `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties are the best to use and the ones most likely to supply the *correct* values at any given time.

Comment: @pushpraj Any ideas how I can use that for moving and resizing objects?

Comment: @Chris why aren't you using `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform`? It seems to me it's the perfect way to move and resize controls.

Comment: Manipulation events are primary meant for touch devices, but it is not difficult to make it work with Mouse, here is a tutorial on the same http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices.aspx . I was wondering if you could share some details about the resizable elements, like where you place them? how you resize? & other details like position of resize handles. appreciated if you can provide a working sample of your app.